# Asked to determine the factor of safety in operation.

Tags: physics

Asked to determine the factor of safety in operation. I understand that Fs = max allowable stress/ actual stress. However the information given is (ultimate tensile stress = 490mn/m2 and the ultimate shear stress = 290mn/m2. How do i work out the max allowable stress using the information given?

Comment: Where is the original question - in a book? on a webpage?

Comment: The 14mm diameter steel bolt with modulus of elasticity of 210GPa and modulus of rigidity of 85 GPa shown in the diagram below holds two components together. The thickness of the bolted interface of the components is 18mm. To 2 decimal places, for the given loading;    Assuming the ultimate tensile stress is 490MN/m2 and the ultimate shear stress is 290MN/m2 determine the factor of safety in operation. The factor of safety = max allowable stress / actual stress

Comment: i just want to know how to determine the max allowable stress using the shear and tensile strength??